# How to crop / margin a website?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m currently struggling with a CSS3 / HTML 5 problem. I set up a one pager using bootstrap in order to get it properly responsive , however I struggle with the following problem:

My website tends to "overlap" on the right border, see here this is the right outer border of my website:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e88zowlc23trry/Bildschirmfoto%202014-10-28%20um%2015.10.45.png?dl=0

There is an overlapping amount of circa 5px across my whole website and I have no clue on how I could "crop" my website or how to reduce the width properly so that this overlaps disappears.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: some code is welcomed

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you could post some code?

My first thought would be to try:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

in the CSS.

Comment: Found the problem: It was an oversized image pushing the borders of the website into overlapse.